# Electron-React-Boilerplate 4.0: Property 'electron' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. Did you mean 'Electron'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I am trying to call the IPCrenderer through the built-in context bridge and receive the following error:

```
Property 'electron' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. Did you mean 'Electron'?
```

I have added tailwind CSS but can not imagine that is causing the issue here.  Below is my code.

**App.tsx**

```jsx
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.global.css';

const Login = () => {
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.onButtonClick('Button Clicked');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
        className="bg-black text-white p-2 font-bold rounded-xl shadow-xl outline-none hover:bg-gray-500 transform hover:scale-110"
      >
        Login &gt;
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**main.tsx** (code snippet added in event listener section)

```jsx
ipcMain.on('button-example', (arg) => {
  console.log(arg);
});
```

**preload.js**

```jsx
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  ipcRenderer: {
    onButtonClick() {
      ipcRenderer.send('button-example', 'Button Clicked');
    },
  },
});
```

Any guidance on this topic would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

@FBSdeveloper,

I had the same issue too. After I searched the internet, I came up with this solution:-

Edit your index.tsx from something like this:-

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

to something like this:-

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: any;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Now you can use window.electron anywhere in the renderer.
This fixed the problem for me. You could also add this in the App.js file.

Although I have not tested it, you can do something like this too:-

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  hworld: "Hello world" // window.electron.hworld is a string ("Hello world")
});
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    electron: {
      hworld: string // Since you know window.electron.hworld is a string
    }
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an index.d.ts file to your project's root directory/src folder, and supply your type interfaces there.

**Example:**

```
/src/index.d.ts

export {}

declare global {
  interface InterfaceName {
    someProperty: any
  }

  ...
}
```